# Proper procedure for ensuring JRE compatibility (32 or 64-bit)

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit

I recently wrote an application for a teacher on campus to use with her class.  Upon distributing I came to realize the application requires a 32-bit JRE.  Is there a way to support both JREs or should I simply inform the user the application requires 32-bit Java 8?

Comment: Requires a 32-bit JRE why? Did you build some JNI into it?

Comment: No, it is a simple application but does include several other libraries such as JFreeChart and the JavaFX datePicker.  Could this be the reason?

Comment: Not unless they in turn have JNI components. What makes you think it needs 32 bits?

Comment: The teacher had trouble using the application.  I confirmed by installing 64 bit JRE on my server and the application would not work without the 32 bit JRE.

Comment: The teacher had *what* trouble? and you confirmed it *how?* Please answer the questions properly. You would expect no less for your own question.

Comment: My apologies, my response was somewhat ambiguous. The teacher I developed the application for was unable to open the application, I had instructed her to install Java 8 and provided her with a link for the 64-bit JRE.  It was not until I linked her to a 32-bit JRE that it would open for her.  I confirmed by placing the application on my Windows Server which had no Java installation, installed the 64-bit JRE and it would not open for me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Java application >>really<< requires a 32bit JVM, that must be because it depends on 32bit native libraries that are not part of the standard JRE install; i.e. native libraries that you have written yourself, or that come from a third-party source.

If that is the case, you have to have some way to ensure that the relevant machines have the right libraries (32 bit or 64 bit) installed.  You need to do this *whichever* platform you use.

If no native libraries are involved then you are mistaken that your application requires a 32 bit JRE.  Pure Java applications are 32 / 64 bit agnostic.

Comment: It must be one of the libraries I am using then either the JFreeChart or JavaFX.  I have the application wrapped using JSmooth that will download the proper JRE for windows but for linux/mac users I am unsure of the proper way to handle this.

Comment: It works on x64 now.  I found a couple unused libraries included in the project, one of which must have been using native libraries.  Thank you for the information!